# How to use pqdict with instances in PYTHON

Tags: python

I am working on my homework and have a problem. I am trying to run:

for move in next_moves:

new_state = copy.deepcopy(state)

```
            new_state.doMove(move)

            print(new_state)

            pq[new_state] = self.utility(new_state)
```

new_state is an instance of the class amazons_board. Anyway I get the error:

Exception in thread Thread-4:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Python34\lib\threading.py", line 921, in _bootstrap_inner

```
self.run()
```

File "C:\Python34\lib\threading.py", line 869, in run

```
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
```

File "C:\Users\Eli\workspace\HW2\amazons\utils.py", line 36, in

function_wrapper

```
result = func(*args, **kwargs)
```

File "C:\Users\Eli\workspace\HW2\amazons\utils.py", line 159, in search

```
pq[new_state] = self.utility(new_state)
```

File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pqdict__init__.py", line 168, in

**setitem**

```
pos = position[key]
```

File "C:\Users\Eli\workspace\HW2\amazons\amazons_board.py", line 95, in

**hash**

```
return hash(','.join(self.board) + self.curr_player)
```

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found

When I remove the last line (pq[new_state] = self.utility(new_state)), There is no error, so the error is in this line. How can I use pqdict with instances?

By the way I can do it with other sort. Is it worth working with other sort?

Thanks in Advance, 
Eli Borodach

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. the problem was in the hash function of the object. Because pqdict is a dictionnary the key has to be immutable and that is why there is a need to use a hash function...

Thanks anyway